# Creating YAML for Kubernetes with Python3

Tags: python-3.x, kubernetes, yaml, pyyaml

I am trying to create my Role YAML file for Kubernetes and I am getting stuck with this specific section of the needed YAML:

```
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

I have tried to add it as a dictionary and then a list with a dictionary inside that for the -apiGroups line, but that then causes issues with the rest of the arguments for rules. I also am having issues with the [] showing up just like that when I am using yaml.dump even though I specify `default_flow_style=False`

```
def create_role_yml(role_filename, team_name, group_user):
    """
    https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/
    access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole
    """

    yml_file_kubernetes_data = dict(

        apiVersion='rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1',
        kind='Role',
        metadata=dict(
            namespace=team_name,
            name=group_user,
            ),
        rules={
            [{'apiGroups':""}],
            'resourses': '[pods]',
            'verbs':'[get, watch, list]'}

        )

    with open(role_filename, 'w') as outfile:
        yaml.dump(yml_file_kubernetes_data, outfile, 
                  default_flow_style=False)
```

I would like to open the YAML and it to look exactly like the Kubernetes reference YAML:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: pod-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

but I am getting the [ ] seperated, and no - for apiGroup. This is my result:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: pod-reader
rules:
apiGroups:
- "" # "" indicates the core API group
resources: 
- "pods"
verbs: 
-"get"
-"watch"
-"list"
```

Comment: Are you sure thre are no spaces after the sequence item indicator (`-`) in your output (the last three lines of your post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you try to do is not possible with the normal parameters you can hand to PyYAML's `dump()`,
which gives you only very course control using `default_flow_style`

- `True`: everything is flow style (JSON like)
- `False`: everything is block style
- `None`: leaf collections are flow style, and the rest block style

You reference YAML has both block style leaf collections: the value
for the key `metadata`, as well as flow style leaf collections: the
value for the key `verbs`. Without hacking the representer you cannot
achieve this in PyYAML.

The way more easy way to generate YAML in your particular form is by
read-modify-write your expected YAML with a parser that knows how to
keep the formatting. You can do that with `ruamel.yaml`, which is
specifically developed to preserve these kind of things (disclaimer: I
am the author of that package).

If your input file is `input.yaml`:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace:
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", 'list']
```

(the single entry under `metadata` is on purpose, but you could specify both, or none if
you assign instead of update)

And the following program:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
"""

in_file = Path("input.yaml")
out_file = Path("output.yaml")

team_name = "default"
group_user = "pod-reader"


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(in_file)
data["metadata"].update(dict(namespace=team_name, name=group_user))
yaml.dump(data, out_file)
```

gives `output.yaml`:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: pod-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", 'list']
```

Please note that apart from the block/flow style, also the single/double quotes
from the original and the comment are preserved. Your indentation
already matches the default, so that is not explicity set (`yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=2, offset=0)`).

Answer (score 0):

The rules are actually an array of maps, so you'll want to change it to look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import yaml

yml_file_kubernetes_data = dict(

    apiVersion='rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1',
    kind='Role',
    metadata=dict(
        namespace='something',
        name='group',
        ),
    rules=[
        {
            'apiGroups': '',
            'resources': [ 'pods' ],
            'verbs': [ 'get', 'watch', 'list' ],
        }
    ],
    )

with open('rbac.yml', 'w') as outfile:
    yaml.dump(yml_file_kubernetes_data, outfile,
              default_flow_style=False)
```

If you want to explicitly use the [] array notation, you'll need to use something like ruamel.yml - honestly, it's really not worth it though. This is valid YAML